# How to incorporate a series of stored procedures inside a larger stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I`m hitting a block here in SQL server , I have a bunch of small insert stored procedures, and I want to call upon them when creating one unified procedure.

I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [Member] 
(
    [MemberID] Int IDENTITY(1,1),
    [ProgID] int,
    [MemberCardID] int,
    [CECID] int,
    [MFirstName] VarChar (60),
    [MLastName] VarChar (60),
    [MDateJoined] DateTime,
    PRIMARY KEY ([MemberID]), 
    FOREIGN KEY ([ProgID]) REFERENCES [Program]
);

CREATE TABLE [MemberCard] 
(
    [MemberCardID] int IDENTITY(1,1),
    [MemberID] int,
    [MemberDetailsID] int,
    [MActiveORInactive] varchar (1),
    [Photo] image,
    [LastLogin] DateTime,
    [LoginFreq] Varchar,
    [PaymentUTD] varchar,
    [IssueDate] Date,
    [NoOfCards] int,
    PRIMARY KEY ([MemberCardID]),
    FOREIGN KEY ([MemberID]) REFERENCES [Member] ,
);

CREATE TABLE [MemberDetails] 
(
    [MemberDetailsID] int IDENTITY(1,1),
    [MemberCardID] int,
    [PaymentID] int,
    [CMAddress] Varchar (100),
    [CMCity] VarChar (50),
    [CMEmail] Varchar (100),
    [CMPhone] int ,
    PRIMARY KEY ([MemberDetailsID]),
    FOREIGN KEY ([MemberCardID]) REFERENCES [MemberCard]
)

CREATE TABLE [EmergencyContact] 
(
    [CECID] Int IDENTITY(1,1),
    [MemberHistoryID] Int,
    [CECFirstName] VarChar(60),
    [CECLastName] Varchar(60),
    [CECPhone] Int,
    [CECAddress] Varchar ( 100 ),
    [CECDateUpdated] DateTime,
    PRIMARY KEY ([CECID]) ,
    FOREIGN KEY ([MemberHistoryID]) RERERENCES [MemberHistory]
)
```

And I have these smaller procedures:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertMember
    @MFirstName varchar(60),
    @MLastName varchar(60)
AS
    BEGIN TRAN
        DECLARE @MemberID int
        SET @MemberID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

        INSERT INTO Member(MFirstName, MLastName, MDateJoined)
        VALUES (@MFirstName, @MLastName, GETDATE())
        
        IF @@ERROR <> 0 OR @@ROWCOUNT > 1
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRAN
            PRINT 'ERROR Inserting Member'

            SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
            
            RETURN -1
        END
        else
        begin
            Commit Tran
            print 'Member Inserted Successfully'
            return 0
        end
        go


CREATE procedure InsertMemberDetails


@CMAddress varchar(100),
@CMCity varchar (50),
@CMEmail varchar (100),
@CMPhone int

AS
begin tran
        declare @MemberDetailsID int
        set @MemberDetailsId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        insert into MemberDetails(CMAddress,CMCity,CMEmail,CMPhone)
        values (@CMAddress,@CMCity,@CMEmail,@CMPhone)

        if @@ERROR <> 0 or @@ROWCOUNT >1
        begin
                ROLLBACK TRAN
                print 'ERROR Inserting MemberDetails!!!'
                select ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
            
                return -1
        end
        else
        begin
            Commit Tran
            print 'MemberDetails Inserted Successfully'
            return 0
        end
        go

CREATE procedure InsertEmergencyContact


@CECFirstName varchar(60),
@CECLastName varchar (60),
@CECPhone int ,
@CECAddress varchar (100)



AS
begin tran
        declare @CECID int
        set @CECID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        insert into EmergencyContact(CECFirstName,CECLastName,CECPhone,CECAddress,CECDateUpdated)
        values (@CECFirstName,@CECLastName,@CECPhone,@CECAddress,Getdate())

        if @@ERROR <> 0 or @@ROWCOUNT >1
        begin
                ROLLBACK TRAN
                print 'ERROR Inserting Emergency Contact Details!!!'
                select ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
            
                return -1
        end
        else
        begin
            Commit Tran
            print 'Emergency Contact Details Inserted Successfully'
            return 0
        end
        go
```

And I want to create one single procedure where I execute the smaller ones but how do I do that?
Obviously the one below doesn't work:

```
CREATE procedure Proc_InsertNewMember

@MFirstName varchar(60),
@MLastName varchar(60),

@CMAddress varchar(100),
@CMCity varchar(50),
@CMPhone int ,
@CMEmail varchar(100),


@CECFirstName varchar(60),
@CECLastName varchar (60),
@CECPhone int,
@CECAddress Varchar (100),
@CECDateUpdated date

as
begin

    insert into Member (MFirstName,MLastName,MDateJoined) 
                exec InsertMember ( @MFirstName , @MLastName , GetDate())
    declare @MemberID int
    select @MemberID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        exec InsertMemberDetails [@CMAddress,@CMCity,@CMPhone,@CMEmail]
        exec InsertEmergencyContact [@CECFirstName,@CECLastName,@CECPhone,@CECAddress ,@CECDateUpdated]

        end

            if @@error <> 0 or @@rowcount <> 1
                    begin
                            print 'ERROR'
                    end
                    else
                        return -1
        end
```

But how can I call upon them procedures, so that I will just end up with one line that goes:

```
exec Proc_InsertNewMember 'Michael','Goodwin','Za Cool Street','Limerick','7843273',
'dhajsdhjas@dsjai.com','Rachel','Green','2121321','The other cool street','02/02/2020'
```

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Sorry, it is SQL server.

Comment: Its ok for the most part actually, just change remove the square brackets around the procedures parameters and make sure you have the correct number of parameters, your example has too many for ```InsertEmergencyContact```